# How to return HTML from ASP.NET Web API when given url

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller

**I want to create a WEB API that will accept a url and return the url's "HTML" page. Please how should I do this? I believe I have the wrong code. HI am so new to this. Thanks***

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent("https://myurl.com");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: "believe I have the wrong code" why? Please describe the error or unexpected behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean do something like this?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://myurl.com");
    using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
      using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = 
                  new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        response.Content = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks but I am getting this error: " 'System.Net.WebRequest': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' ". do you know what this is?

Comment: Must not be IDisposable. Just remove the using around that line - updated code

Comment: Great That worked fine... But I have one more question: If I wanted to add this to API Controller (that function) to an already made MVC Controller, how till that work? or rephrase my question I want the var "response" to be accessible in my normal MVC controller. How can I link the two? Thanks!!!

Comment: Normal controllers, and API Controllers work slightly different, otherwise if there were the same type you could have a base class with the response in it, that any derived class could access.

Answer (score 0):

My extension for AspNetCore:

```
    public static ContentResult GetDashboardAsHtml(this AbpController controller)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create($"{controller.Request.Scheme}://{controller.Request.Host}/hangfire");

        using var response = request.GetResponse();
        using var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim(),
            ContentType = "text/html"
        };
    }
```